# Order of execution of Post-Functions in Jira looks incorrect

Tags: jira

We use sub-tasks and I want to move parents depending on the status of the sub-tasks. For instance, if a sub-task is moved to In Progress and its parent is in Open then move the parent to In Progress, too.

On the other hand, I want some validation of statuses to make sure statuses of parents and sub-tasks are aligned. I do this validation in a ScriptRunner's listener that listens to a custom event SubTaskTransitionComplete.

I have the following post-functions on the Open -> In Progress transition for sub-tasks:

1. ScriptRunner post-function that changes status of the parent to In Progress
2. Set issue status to the linked status of the destination workflow step (standard one)
3. Re-index an issue to keep indexes in sync with the database (standard one)
4. Fire a SubtaskTransitionComplete event (ScriptRunner)
5. Fire a Generic Event event that can be processed by the listeners (standard one)

But I still get my event listener (that's subscribed to the event, that is fired in post-function #4) telling me that a sub-task is in In Progress status and its parent is in Open, despite the status of the parent should have been changed (and actually it is changed) to the In Progress in the post-function #1.

Could you please help me figure out what's wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can fire two events in a transition and get the expected results

Comment: Hi. Not sure i understand. You mean 2 events after parent and child is transitioned? That won't work really because i report incorrect validation results by email. This way i still will get an email with the incorrect condition of the parent.